# Numpy indexing, using a mask to pick out specific entries of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two arrays:

```
x     # shape(n, m)
mask  # shape(n), where each entry is a number between 0 and m-1
```

My goal is to use `mask` to pick out entries of `x`, such that the result has shape `n`. Explicitly:

```
out[i] = x[i, mask[i]]
```

This can be coded easily using a for loop

```
out = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    out[i] = x[i, mask[i]]
```

I was hoping to vectorize this using numpy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 6, 6

x = np.arange(n * m).reshape(n, m)
mask = np.random.randint(m, size=n)

out = x[np.arange(n), mask]
```

```
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
>>> mask
array([2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3])
>>> out
array([ 2, 10, 14, 20, 29, 33])
```